# Excel dynamic range to calculate percentages

Tags: excel, vba

I have three columns in my table date, day and quantity.  I want to be able to calculate the quantity percentages by day.

```
Date | DAY | QUANTITY
 1   | MON |    3
 2   | TUE |    6
 3   | WED |    3
 4   | THU |    1
....
 8   | MON |    3
 9   | TUE |    1
```

I'm sure there has to be an easier way than hard coding it.

For example I want a formula to calculate total quant on monday over the total which would be 3 + 3 /17 for the values listed and display it in its own cell.

Do i need to use vba or can i just write a formula?

Comment: You can just write a formula.

Comment: @Ron how do i write a formula to go through the DAY column and then add the totals

Comment: =sum(c:c) will sum the entries in column C

Comment: @pnuts That reason makes no sense to me either

Comment: @pnuts Curiouser and curiouser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formula to divide the sum of the Monday quantities by the sum of the total:

```
=SUMIF(B:B,"MON",C:C)/SUM(C:C)
```